# Error in normalizePath export igraph to graphviz

Tags: r, export, igraph, graphviz

I'm trying to export an igraph from r to graphviz but I get the the following error message:

Error in normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) : 
  path[1]="C:\R\graphviz-1.8.10.src.zip\graphviz-1.8.10": The system cannot find the path specified

The code Im running is:

```
dot.plot <- function(g) {
tmpfile <- tempfile(pattern='dot', fileext='.dot')
print(tmpfile)
g %>% write_graph(tmpfile, "dot")
handle <- spawn_process('C:\\R\\graphviz-1.8.10.src.zip\\graphviz-1.8.10', c('-Tpng', '-O', tmpfile))
Sys.sleep(5) 
pngimg <- readPNG(paste(tmpfile, '.png', sep=''))
grid.raster(pngimg)
}
```

Any ideas in how I can solve this error?

Comment: Did you install graphviz ? looks like you try to run something out of the zip file but this is also a directory (I think) I think it should have at least `dot.exe` as name of the executable appended.

Comment: Yes I am pretty sure graphviz is installed, any way I can test if the instalation went through?

Comment: In the dotneato file I see:
dot.1, dot.c, dot.dep, dot.dsp, dot.dsw, dot.mak, dot.ncb, dot.plg, and a couple more but no dot.exe

Comment: Checking, see if you can start dot in a terminal window e.g. by means `dot -V` you can also give the command `where dot` to see where the executable resides. I the file `graphviz-1.8.10.src.zip` a recent file as the current version of graphviz is 2.38. Where did you obtain `graphviz-1.8.10.src.zip`

Comment: I downloaded it from: https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/Download/Download_windows.html

Comment: But why is it called `graphviz-1.8.10.src.zip` I see theer only `graphviz-2.38.zip` and `graphviz-2.38.msi`.

Comment: I'm not sure, I just downloaded the graphviz-2.38.msi file but it's still not working

Comment: Just downloading is not enough, you have to install it as well and also look at the sentence 'you will need to set the PATH variable yourself' (or use the full path in the call).

Comment: I am fairly new at this, could you walk me through the instalation and set PATH variable please?

Comment: install the msi, just double click. Setting the path variable: Google e.g. 'set path variable windows'

Comment: still getting the same error

Comment: Did you adjust your code? did you try `dot -V`?

Comment: The code I'm running now is:
 `dot.plot <- function(g) {
  tmpfile <- tempfile(pattern='dot', fileext='.dot')
  print(tmpfile)
  g %>% write_graph(tmpfile, "dot")
  handle <- spawn_process ('C:/R/graphviz-2.38/release/bin', c('-Tpng', '-O', tmpfile))
  Sys.sleep(5) # Sleep to make sure dot has finished
  pngimg <- readPNG(paste(tmpfile, '.png', sep=''))
  grid.raster(pngimg)
}`

Comment: Edit the new code into the question (e.g. as a separate section). What is the result of `dot -V`? and `where dot`? Why do you use `C:/R/graphviz-2.38/release/bin` and not `C:/R/graphviz-2.38/release/bin/dot.exe` and probably the slashes`/` should be backslashes `\\` as well.

Comment: Result of `dot -V` is `Error: object 'dot' not found` result of `Where dot` is  `Error: unexpected symbol in "Where dot" `

Comment: Very strange, when `dot` cannot be found in a terminal window I would expect something like `'dot' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.` and for the `where` command I would expect `INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).` You double clicked the msi file and followed the instructions? Where did it want to install the stuff ? or did you give a different directory? Which version of windows ae you using?

Comment: I just restarded my computer and tried dot- V and where dot again and I get the errors you suggested. `'dot' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` and `INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).`  any ideas? I'm using windows 7

Comment: Well a bit on track again. Looks like you havn't set the PATH but this is probably not a big issue. Can you locate the `dot.exe` by searching the disk (so we can add this `path + dot.exe` to your spawn command)?

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin\dot.exe

Comment: btw to your knowledge, is there any other way to export igraph without using graphviz? the graph I am obtaining with igraphs does not look very appealing hence the reason I am trying to export it.

Comment: Regarding the last question: no idea. Regarding the found path what happens when you use that in the spawn  statement?

Comment: Hi, I changed the path in the spawn statement to `handle <- spawn_process ('C:/Program Files (x86)/Graphviz2.38/bin/dot.exe', c('-Tpng', '-O', tmpfile))` and I get the error msg `Error in readPNG(paste(tmpfile, ".png", sep = "")) : 
  unable to open C:\Users\MANZ16~1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpcV5BAz\dot2a7058ed72c9.dot.png`

Comment: Looks like it cannot read the generated png file, probably to do with the space in your directory name., is the file present ? and if present can you open it with a browser or a package like paint or irfanview or gimp?